# WebGL: cancelled network request for video in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I am trying to load a video into a webgl implementation for a texture. The implementation works fine for firefox but i get an error in chrome and no texture:

```
INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no video
```

When I check the netowrk requests, it shows that the video has been cancelled in chrome. 
I found that the video plays normally in its HTML element when

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
```

Is disabled in the JS. however, there is audio in from the video in chrome.
Any thoughts?

init() and draw() are where everything takes place near the bottom half of the JS

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-debug.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cuon-utils.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cuon-matrix.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="prog5.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="chest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cube.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
            <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
                    precision mediump float;

                    uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
                    uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
                    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
                    uniform vec4 lightPosition;

                    attribute vec4 vertexPosition;  
                    attribute vec3 vertexNormal;
                    attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;                              

                    varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
                    varying vec3 fragmentLight;
                    varying vec3 fragmentView;
                    varying vec4 fragmentPosition; 
                    varying vec2 fragmentTexCoord;                              

                    void main() {
                            mat4 modelViewMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

                            vec4 p = modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition;
                            vec4 q = viewMatrix * lightPosition;                            

                            fragmentPosition    = vertexPosition; 
                            fragmentNormal      = normalize(mat3(modelViewMatrix) * vertexNormal);
                            fragmentLight       = normalize(vec3(q - p));
                            fragmentView        = normalize(vec3(-p));
                            fragmentTexCoord    = vertexTexCoord;               

                            gl_Position     = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition;
                    }
            </script>
            <script id="lightingFragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
                    precision mediump float;

                    varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
                    varying vec3 fragmentLight;
                    varying vec3 fragmentView;
                    varying vec4 fragmentPosition; 
                    varying vec2 fragmentTexCoord;

                    uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
                    uniform vec3 modelColor;
                    uniform vec3 lightColor;

                    void main() {
                            vec3 n = normalize(fragmentNormal);
                            vec3 l = normalize(fragmentLight);
                            vec3 v = normalize(fragmentView);
                            vec3 h = normalize(l + v);
                            vec4 modelColor          = texture2D(modelTexture, fragmentTexCoord);

                            float d = max(dot(l,n) , 0.0);
                            float s = pow(max(dot(h, n), 0.0), 10.0);

                            vec3 fragmentColor  = vec3(modelColor) * lightColor * d + lightColor * s;

                            gl_FragColor        = vec4(fragmentColor, 1.0); 
                    }
            </script> 
            <center>
                <canvas id="webgl" width="500px" height="500px">
                    This content requires <a href="http://get.webgl.org/">WebGL</a>
                </canvas>
                <font face ="Arial">
                    <br>
                    Light Source Position
                    <br>
                    X-AXIS<input id="x-light" type="range" min="-5.0" max="5.0" value="0" step="0.1" oninput="refresh()">
                    <br>
                    Y-AXIS <input id="y-light" type="range" min="-5.0" max="5.0" value="0" step="0.1" oninput="refresh()">
                    <br>
                    Z-AXIS<input id="z-light" type="range" min="-5.0" max="5.0" value="0" step="0.1" oninput="refresh()">
                </font>
            </center>
        <video id="video" src="Firefox.ogv" autoplay style="display:none;">
      Your browser doesn't appear to support the <code>&lt;video&gt;</code> element.
        </video>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var gl;
var canvas;

var dragging = false;
var texShader;
var chestModel;

var xValue = 0;
var yValue = 0;
var zValue = 0;

var modelRotationX = 0;
var modelRotationY = 0;
var lastClientX;
var lastClientY;

var copyVideo;
var video;
var modelTexture;

//refresh function used to request animation frame after moving slider in HTML
function refresh(){
    xValue = document.getElementById("x-light").value;
    yValue = document.getElementById("y-light").value;
    zValue = document.getElementById("z-light").value;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

//define 'flatten' function to flatten tables to single array
function flatten(a) {    
    return a.reduce(function (b, v) { b.push.apply(b, v); return b }, [])   
}

//create tumble interaction functions to click and drag cube
function onmousedown(event){
    dragging    = true;
    lastClientX = event.clientX;
    lastClientY = event.clientY;
}

function onmouseup(event){ 
    dragging = false;
}

/*using clientX and clientY derived from click event, use to create modelX and Y 
rotation before passing to model matrices rotation transformations*/
function onmousemove(event){
    //console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    if (dragging){  
        var dX = event.clientX - lastClientX;
        var dY = event.clientY - lastClientY;

        modelRotationY = modelRotationY + dX;
        modelRotationX = modelRotationX + dY;


        if (modelRotationX > 90.0){
            modelRotationX = 90.0;
        }

        if (modelRotationX < -90.0){
            modelRotationX = -90.0;
        }

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
     lastClientX = event.clientX;
     lastClientY = event.clientY;

}
function startVideo() {
  video.play();
  intervalID = setInterval(draw, 15);
}

function videoDone() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}


//define Shader object constructor function
function Shader(vertexId, fragmentId){

    this.program = createProgram(gl, document.getElementById( vertexId).text,
                                     document.getElementById(fragmentId).text);

    this.modelMatrixLocation         = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'modelMatrix');
    this.viewMatrixLocation          = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'viewMatrix');
    this.projectionMatrixLocation    = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'projectionMatrix');
    this.vertexPositionLocation      = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexPosition'); 
    this.lightPositionLocation       = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'lightPosition');
    this.modelColorLocation          = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'modelColor');
    this.lightColorLocation          = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'lightColor');
    this.vertexNormalLocation        = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexNormal');
    this.vertexTexCoordLocation      = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'vertexTexCoord');

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexPositionLocation);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexNormalLocation);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexTexCoordLocation);
}

//define use() method for Shader objects
Shader.prototype.use = function(projectionMatrix, modelMatrix, viewMatrix){

    gl.useProgram(this.program);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.modelMatrixLocation, false, modelMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.viewMatrixLocation, false, viewMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.projectionMatrixLocation, false, projectionMatrix.elements);

    gl.uniform4f(this.lightPositionLocation, xValue, yValue, zValue, 0.0);
    gl.uniform3f(this.modelColorLocation, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2);
    gl.uniform3f(this.lightColorLocation, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

//define Model object constructor function
function Model(positions, triangles, normals, texCoords){
    //initialize buffer objects
    this.positionBuffer  = gl.createBuffer();
    this.triangleBuffer  = gl.createBuffer();
    this.normalsBuffer   = gl.createBuffer();
    this.texCoordBuffer  = gl.createBuffer();


    //copy vertex data from array in CPU onto GPU
    this.positionArray = new Float32Array(flatten(positions));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);    

    //copy triangle data from array in CPU onto GPU
    this.triangleArray = new Uint16Array(flatten(triangles));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.normalsArray = new Float32Array(flatten(normals));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalsBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalsArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.textCoordArray = new Float32Array(flatten(texCoords));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textCoordArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

//define draw() method for Model objects to bind barray buffers
Model.prototype.draw = function(shader){

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexPositionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalsBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexNormalLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);    
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexTexCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.triangleArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


}

//initizlize texture object
function loadTexture(image, texture){
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);                                                        
}


function init(){

    //initialize GL context
    canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
    gl = getWebGLContext(canvas, false);

    canvas.onmousedown  = onmousedown;
    canvas.onmouseup    = onmouseup;
    canvas.onmousemove  = onmousemove;

    //instantiate shader objects for each defined shader
    texShader           = new Shader('vertexShader', 'lightingFragmentShader');    
    //instantiate model objects for each model
    chestModel          = new Model(chest.positions, chest.triangles, chest.normals, chest.texCoords);
    modelTexture    = gl.createTexture();


   video = document.getElementById('video');



   /*
     video.onload   = function() {
       loadTexture(video, modelTexture);
    } 
    */

     video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", startVideo, true);
    video.addEventListener("ended", videoDone, true);


    loadTexture(video, modelTexture);
    video.src = 'Firefox.ogv';
    video.crossOrigin  = "anonymous";       
    video.preload = "auto";
   //video.load();
   // video.play();



    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);                               
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //request animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);    

}


function draw(){

    updateTexture();

    //compose matrices for transformations
    var viewMatrix          = new Matrix4();
    var projectionMatrix    = new Matrix4();  

    viewMatrix.translate(0.0, 0.0, -1.8);
    projectionMatrix.perspective(90, 1, 1, 10);

    //set color and refresh rendering for canvas       
    gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*instantiate model matrices for each respective model 
      and draw models with applied shader*/
    var chestModelMatrix    = new Matrix4();
    chestModelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationX, 1, 0, 0 );
    chestModelMatrix.rotate(modelRotationY, 0, 1, 0 ); 
    chestModelMatrix.translate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

    //set uniform locations and apply shader to designated model
    texShader.use(projectionMatrix, chestModelMatrix, viewMatrix);    
    chestModel.draw(texShader);

}



function updateTexture() {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, modelTexture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
}
```

Some of my additional sources such as Firefox.ogv and the chest model can be found here:

https://github.com/TacoB0t/CSC43/tree/prog/prog5

I'm curious if it has anything to do with my element:

```
<video id="video" src="Firefox.ogv" autoplay style="display:none;">
      Your browser doesn't appear to support the <code>&lt;video&gt;</code> element.
</video>
```

I am also setting the following in my JS:

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
video.src = 'Firefox.ogv';
```

Comment: video errors have nothing to do with WebGL

Comment: probably not related to your issue, but you have to set the `crossOrigin` attribute before setting the mediaElement `src` if you want it to have some effect.

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely getting a network request cancelled message because you're loading 2 videos. The first video is specified in your video tag in HTML

```
<video id="video" src="Firefox.ogv" ...
```

So chrome starts downloading that video

That then gets replaced in JavaScript with this line

```
video.src = 'Firefox.ogv';
```

So chrome cancels the original request and starts downloading the video set by JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I tried to leave the HTML element as an empty video element and it still works in firefox but I now get this error in chrome: DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.